# Android tests without emulator

Tags: android, testing

Is it possible to run some android tests for example: AndroidTestCase without using emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an Android emulator or Android device to run Android APK files, including those APK files that implement AndroidTestCase subclasses used to test other APK file contents.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use external testing frameworks for that, such as [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/).

See also: [Best practices for unit testing Android apps](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check [Roboelectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric).